# PostgreSQL query error when using PHP

Tags: postgresql, postgis

When I run a PostgreSQL query containing `::geometry` casting, I get a `type "geometry" does not exist` error. I am using php5-pgsql V5.3.10, php5-fpm 5.4.13, Laravel 4, Postgresql 9.1, PostGIS 2.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. `geometry` type is PostGIS-specific.

Without the casting, the query runs fine. The original query also works fine when queried directly against the PostgreSQL database using pgAdmin3. Why is this?

**Query**

```
$busstops = DB::connection('pgsql')
    ->table('locations')
    ->select(DB::raw('geog::geometry as lat, geog::geometry as lng'))
    ->get();
```

**Query without casting (No errors)**

```
$busstops = DB::connection('pgsql')
    ->table('locations')
    ->select(DB::raw('geog as lat, geog as lng'))
    ->get();
```

**Error:**

`Exception: SQLSTATE[42704]: Undefined object: 7 ERROR: type "geometry" does not exist
LINE 1: select geog::geometry as lat from "locations"
^ (SQL: select geog::geometry as lat from "locations") (Bindings: array (
))`

---

**\dT geometry**

```
                     List of data types
 Schema |   Name   |               Description
--------+----------+-----------------------------------------
 public | geometry | postgis type: Planar spatial data type.
(1 row)
```

Comment: Any chance you installed the `geometry` type into a separate schema that's on the `search_path` in manual queries but not via your tool? Or that you're not really connecting to the same DB in your tool and manual queries?

Comment: @CraigRinger I ran `CREATE EXTENSION postgis; CREATE EXTENSION postgis-topology;` when connected to the database, which I assumed (incorrectly?) that it will install `geometry` type for all schemas? I do have multiple schemas, how do I install `geometry` type for a specfic/all schemas?

Comment: You don't have to install the type for each schema. You can optionally install extensions in their own schema, in which case that  schema must be on the `search_path` for the extension to be usable. You don't seem to have done that so I doubt this is a search_path issue. Confirm with `\dT geometry` in `psql`, confirm what schema the `geometry` type is listed as being in. If it's installed in `public` then perhaps your `search_path` is being set so that it doesn't include the `public` schema by your app?

Comment: @CraigRinger Updated question with the output. Seems like its only available in the `public` schema!!

Comment: Yep, so you need to make sure the `public` schema is always on the `search_path`, or install it do a *different* schema that contains nothing but PostGIS (called, say, `postgis`) and make sure that's always on the `search_path`. See the `SCHEMA` clause of `CREATE EXTENSION`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html

Comment: @CraigRinger `SHOW search_path;` outputs `"#user", public` so `public` was already on the `search_path`... `CREATE EXTENSION postgis SCHEMA warehouse;` gives the error `ERROR:  extension "postgis" already exists`. Doing `ALTER EXTENSION postgis SET SCHEMA warehouse;` made the query work, but only for the `warehouse` schema :(

Comment: You'd need to create a `postgis` schema, move the extension into it, and make sure the `postgis` schema is always on the search path. How to ensure it's always on the search path depends on how your application is manipulating the search path when switching schemas; I don't do PHP/Laravel so I can't really speak on that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application is switching the `search_path` around so that `public` isn't on the `search_path`. By default extensions are installed into `public`, so you're finding that `geometry` and the other PostGIS types and functions become unavailable from the application when it switches the `search_path`.

You need to:

- Create a new schema `postgis`;
- Move the PostGIS extension into the `postgis` schema; and
- Make sure that the new `postgis` schema is *always* on the `search_path`, probably using application-specific settings

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that certain schemas are *always* in the search path?